# android image view problem still persist

Tags: android

My project is build in 2.2. I have one image view and i have set one image of 285 X 212 to the image view. I have set the Image view properties :

```
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/eMyImage" android:adjustViewBounds="true"></ImageView>
```

But the Image which is shown on the imageview  is smaller than its actual size.

But if a build the project in 1.5 the image is shown in its actual size.

What should be the problem guys?

Thanks

Comment: What device or emulator configuration are you testing on when you get the small image?

Comment: perhaps your running into an issue with pixel density based on the devices/emulators your testing with?

Comment: I am testing n real device HTC legend.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the minHeight and minWidth attributes?

Comment: Then do it. They should keep it at the given size. Maybe it's a scaling issue.